# RxJS filter date

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have two arrays, for example:

```
var a1 = ["1","3","4","5"]
var a2 = ["1","6","3","5"]
```

the second array is used as a storage.

I want to compare this two arrays, so for example, the number 4 is in `a1` but not in `a2`, so I want push the number 4 into `a2`.
So every number does not contain already in a2 should be pushed into it.

How can I solve this scenario with rxjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of would be the following:

```
var a1 = ["1","3","4","5"];
var a2 = ["1","6","3","5"];

Observable.from(a1)
    .filter(val => a2.indexOf(val) === -1)
    .subscribe(val => {
        a2.push(val);
    });

console.log(a2);
```

This prints to console:

```
[ '1', '6', '3', '5', '4' ]
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/gabesog/1/edit